# Merging borders with CSS for table/div

Tags: html, css

I have build a div layout, and there must be border around every div.

The problem is that when two divs are next to eachother, there will be double borders.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y7Kee/

I have also set `border-collapse: collapse;` on table, div, td, th, but that does not seem to work.

EDIT:

if border collapse does not work with DIV, any other suggestions, how can I merge the borders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Border collapsing only works on table cells.  You can use CSS rules to select particular elements and apply border widths where it would make sense to have them.

```
div {
    border:1px solid;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    border-right-width: 0;
}
td:last-child div {
    border-right-width: 1px;
}
div:last-child {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/Y7Kee/1/

Answer (score 1):

Offset the left and top of the divs by -1:

```
div {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border:1px solid;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```